# EC2 FTP Service Not Starting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

**Question**
How do I start an 'out-of-the-box' FTP Service on EC2 Ubuntu (14) Server ?

**Background**
I have a running EC2 instance, and now want to add a FTP Server/service to it.
I've read loads of guides and answers, but it seems I can't even go past the first step:

I installed using 'sudo apt-get install vsftpd'.
Then started the service using 'sudo service vsftpd start'.
It all seemed just fine, but actually, it doesn't start. using 'sudo service vsftpd stop'
returns 'unknown instance:'. I guess it crushed right after.

How can I help you help me understand the issue?

**Some more info:**
At start I did all those security and other tricks out there (from passive ftp to opening ports on the console, which are still open), but ended up reinstalling
vsftpd just to see if I can start it. Well, I can't :/

Maybe I should note that I connect to my server using ssh with the AWS .pem file (containing the key), and my server has the normal user-pass login disabled (I hope I describe it correctly), meaning I don't need any password for a sudo, for example.

Furthermore, I thought maybe there is another service running on the 21 port. I tried running the service on a different port with no luck (using port_number=xx in the .conf file).

thx.

Answer (score 1):

There's basically something wrong with the vsftpd executable in Ubuntu 14.04 (and possibly incompatible kernel)  The version is:

```
# vsftpd -v
vsftpd: version 3.0.2
```

and the logs show this:

```
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954731] CPU: 0 PID: 15953 Comm: vsftpd Tainted: G    B        3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954733]  ffff880005002000 ffff8800050b1c70 ffffffff81715a64 00007fed3623b000
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954737]  ffff8800050b1cb8 ffffffff81174183 8000000cce578965 00000007fed3623b
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954739]  ffff8800050211d8 ffffea0000000000 00007fed3623b000 00007fed3623c000
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954742] Call Trace:
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954749]  [<ffffffff81715a64>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954754]  [<ffffffff81174183>] print_bad_pte+0x1a3/0x250
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954758]  [<ffffffff81175b67>] unmap_page_range+0x717/0x7f0
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954761]  [<ffffffff81175cc1>] unmap_single_vma+0x81/0xf0
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954764]  [<ffffffff81176d39>] unmap_vmas+0x49/0x90
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954768]  [<ffffffff8117feec>] exit_mmap+0x9c/0x170
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954771]  [<ffffffff8106482c>] mmput+0x5c/0x120
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954775]  [<ffffffff81069bbc>] do_exit+0x26c/0xa50
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954778]  [<ffffffff8109dd84>] ? vtime_account_user+0x54/0x60
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954782]  [<ffffffff8114d52f>] ? context_tracking_user_exit+0x4f/0xc0
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954785]  [<ffffffff8106a41f>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954788]  [<ffffffff8106a494>] SyS_exit_group+0x14/0x20
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954791]  [<ffffffff8172663f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954873] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:ffff880024ac8e00 idx:0 val:-1
May  1 20:42:37 ip-x-x-x-x kernel: [32593770.954882] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:ffff880024ac8e00 idx:1 val:1
```

This works fine under Ubuntu 12.04 which runs vsftpd version:

```
vsftpd -v
vsftpd: version 2.3.5
```

I would try installing directly from source:

https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html

Comment: Thx for the reply.  
I tried to install using sudo apt-get vsftpd 2.3.5 and it asked if it's ok to install 1GB of content. So either it has to change lot's of core code or the command is wrong.

Do you know how it is possible to use the terminal to install directly from the site?

Comment: I decided to use something else instead of ftp.
I'll leave this q unanswered until someone confirms the hack or post a relevant (when available) ubuntu update